# GeoServer log in issue by localhost link

Tags: geoserver, authentication, http

We have upgraded GeoServer version to 2.23.2; Tomcat 9.0.60 and Java 11.0.20. GeoServer deployment was via war file.

The server is externally facing. After the upgrade GeoServer application can be accessed by an external link from another instance, but can't be accessed from the server itself, using a localhost link.

It gets redirected from `http://localhost/geoserver/web/?1` to an external link with the following error:

[image]

Current settings:

[image]

web.xml config has an external link in it:

[image]

Does anyone know the solutions?

Comment: Updated question description.

Answer (score 0):

I think Java JDK or JRE should be reinstalled and configured through executables/Windows binary.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Could you please provide a bit more info about the configuration
through executables/Windows binary for JDK?

Comment: You should re-install the JDK /JRE along with the Geoserver and should use JDK compatible with the Geoserver version you want to work with. After installing the JDK , run the binary file of Geoserver and provide the path of JDK installation from dropdown list. Once the installation completed , check it on localhost with port number you provided during the installtion of geoserver.